# How to install MJRCALC-system in SBCL by Quicklisp

Tags: common-lisp, package, sbcl, quicklisp, asdf

I've installed SBCL with Quicklisp in my Tumbleweed. Quicklisp has also ASDF inbuilt. After that I also intalled MJRCALC-system in Home/quicklisp/local-projects/mjrcalc-folder. Quicklisp (and ASDF) can recognize the system (in SBCL):
(ql:quickload "mjrcalc")
To load "mjrcalc":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    mjrcalc
; Loading "mjrcalc"

("mjrcalc")

The problem is that I can't (or don't know how to) load packages from the mjrcalc-system. I also tried to get a list of the packages in the system without result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

1- look for documentation
2- grep for in-package and/or def.*package